# why user community nickname is displayed instead of Name on user lookup?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Hi i have implemented one lookup LWC component for custom lookup field to search user records. Component working as expected as a system Admin, but as a community user i can able to see nickname (user1234565434) not name but in apex and html i am referring

```
Select Id,name from user
```

In the UI, i can only see nickname but in backend details are populating correctly.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Experience Cloud can be enabled to display Nicknames instead of fullnames to protect your member identities. From your question, this appears to have been enabled in your org.

The [Show Nicknames Instead of full Names in Experience Cloud Site](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_enable_nickname_display.htm&type=5) article covers how to enable this, so you'll be able to use that to disable it.

Just a note though, if this has been enabled in your org then there may be a reason for having done this, so you may need to review why it was enabled and whether it should in fact be disabled.